# making script applicable to only 1 specific google worksheet

Tags: google-sheets

I created this script to apply to only the worksheet with the name "jan" -- however it runs on all the worksheets no matter how I try. Who can help me check what I am doing wrong?

```
function onEdit() { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("jan");
    var r = sheet.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        var time = new Date();
        time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "dd/MM");
        nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function onEdit() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "jan") {
    // DO SOMETHING TO "jan"
    Logger.log("working on sheet jan...");
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, this worked and helped me to build further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To put the above with what you are doing:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("jan");
    var r = sheet.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 3 && activeSheet.getName()=="jan") {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        var time = new Date();
        time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "dd/MM");
        nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
  };
```